# Can graphics driver cause low level crash on a pc? (frozen screen output)

Tags: drivers, crash, hardware-failure

I recently installed a beta nvidia graphics card driver and my pc crashes with frozen screen output.

Comment: yep, could be a graphics driver issue...

Comment: Any other ambiguous questions or is there something specific you need help with?

Comment: Yes; that's the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a graphics driver can cause a low level crash on a PC. Drivers run inside the kernel, which means that if a driver fails, it will cause a BSOD or other kernel crash.